# Maven update links

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, maven-plugin

Hi I'm new in android development and in JAVA. I have Android studio and a new project. I added to my project one dependency on library from maven repository in project properties. So if for example after one year someone will update this library in maven repository, I will need update also link to this library in project settings, or it will load new version of library automatically? Thanks.

Here my .gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.robbypond:mopub-android-sdk:3.2.2d'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
}
```

Comment: It depends... how did you add the dependency? Did you download the JAR and put it somewhere in the project directory? Or did you update a `.gradle` file?

Comment: I'm using gradle, I updated question.

Comment: that particular version is not supposed to be updated. there´ll be a new one so you have to change the version number for your project to be updated

Comment: may I to do configuration to update automatically for the new versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you define your dependency to a fixed version (such as `com.robbypond:mopub-android-sdk:3.2.2d`), the dependency will not be updated. There will simply be no update of the dependency, since after a dependency is released, its contents should be fixed.

If you want to 'automatically upgrade' to a newer version, you might want to use a ['dynamic version'](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules). You can do that like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.robbypond:mopub-android-sdk:3.2.+' // note the + instead of 2d
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.+' // note + instead of 9
}
```

The advantage is that you can get a newer version of the library only if the last part of the version number changes. When the library author adheres to [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), you'll only get bugfix updates but never introduce compile failures due to a changed API.

Another option is to leave out the version number at all. This introduces the risk of getting newer version of an API, possibly breaking your build. I'm mentioning it for completeness only:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.robbypond:mopub-android-sdk' // note the missing :3.2.2d
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query' // note the missing :0.25.9
}
```

Comment: I've got next error after these changes:  file:/C:/AndroidDevelopment/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/googlecode/android-query/android-query//android-query-.pom
         file:/C:/AndroidDevelopment/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/googlecode/android-query/android-query//android-query-.jar
         file:/C:/AndroidDevelopment/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/googlecode/android-query/android-query//android-query-.pom
         file:/C:/AndroidDevelopment/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/googlecode/android-query/android-query//android-query-.jar

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using? You can see that with `gradle -v`. Can you post the exact error message? This looks more like a list of file names... Also please double-check the `dependencies` block (I've updated it).

Comment: I did it according next link 'dynamic version' (see in answer) I need just put  "+" to the version like: compile 'com.robbypond:mopub-android-sdk:3.3.+'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.+'

Comment: Please note that use of dynamic versioning is in general pretty strongly discouraged. Though it seems like you would always want to pick up newer versions, especially releases that are supposed to only be bugfix releases, in practice this tends to make your app or build break at unpredictable times for unpredictable reasons when a library silently changes: "My app worked yesterday but crashes today, why?" You also wouldn't want a library to change underneath you late in the test/release cycle of a project.

Comment: Definitely agree with you, Scott Berta. I always pin my versions, in order to have a reproducible build. Just felt this wasn't the place to diverge into too much of the pro's and con's, but it's definitely something to take into consideration.